# Как натренировать модель в TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Подскажите пожалуйста как имея свои картинки натренировать нейросеть. В Интернете искал все тренирую на готовых картинках. Также я не использую  Colab. Если кто то может объяснить доходчиво.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340129/tensorflow-training-on-my-own-image

Comment: Спасибо прочту!!